# ASP.NET MVC and AngularJs Routing Merge issue

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, html, routes, view

I am trying to merge asp.net MVC and also angularjs routing, but facing issues.
I'll explain the steps on how i did one by one

1. I created a asp.net mvc project on visual studio.
2. Deleted the `about` and `contact` controller and views. Just retained the `home` controller and view.
3. Inside the `home/index` view i.e `index.cshtml` I have the following code:

   ```
   <div>Hello Home from MVC</div>

   <div>
      {{title}}
       <div ng-view></div>
   </div>
   ```

I have also defined an angular app and also few controllers. The controllers just contain `$scope.title` with the controller name. I have also configured my angular app and routing as follows:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute','ui.router' ]);

app.config(function ($routeProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/Templates/Home.html',
        controller: 'homeViewCtrl'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/custList', {
        templateUrl: '/Templates/CustomerList.html',
        controller: 'customerListViewCtrl'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/custDetail', {
        templateUrl: '/Templates/CustomerDetail.html',
        controller: 'customerDetailViewCtrl'
    });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    $locationProvider.html5mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });
})
```

I have three views in a template folder.

`home.html`:

```
<h2>{{title}}</h2>
Hello from home
<br/>
<br/>
<a href="#/custList">Go to customer list view</a>
<br />
<a href="#/custDetail">Go to customer detail view</a>
```

`customerList.html` and `customerDetail.html` which just contains the `customerList` and `customerDetail` respectively inside divs.

When I run the code it will show me the layout page created by asp.net along with index page and get the error in console saying

> ```
> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
> TypeError: $locationProvider.html5mode is not a function
> ```

I tried to resolve it but couldn't. Later I commented the `$locationProvider` line then my code started working. `home.html` inside the template folder was loaded and also I could see those two links for `customerList` and `details` views. But when I click on it, does not load the view nor show any error instead shows this on the browser address bar:

> ```
> http://localhost:57407/#!/#%2FcustList
>
> http://localhost:57407/#!/#%2FcustDetail
> ```

Is there any way to overcome this error and load the view? Help is much appreciated. 
Also the `homeViewCtrl`, `customerListViewCtrl`, `customerDetailViewCtrl` are declared in another file which only gets has `$scope.title` containing the title of the controller.

This is the `ctrl1.js` file:

```
app.controller('Ctrl',['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.title = "Hello World!";
}])

app.controller('homeViewCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.title = "Hello from home angular";
})

app.controller('customerListViewCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.title = "customer List View Controller";
})

app.controller('customerDetailViewCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.title = "customer detail View Controller";
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider',
function($routeProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

 $routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: '/Templates/Home.html',
    controller: 'homeViewCtrl'
});
$routeProvider.when('/custList', {
    templateUrl: '/Templates/CustomerList.html',
    controller: 'customerListViewCtrl'
});
$routeProvider.when('/custDetail', {
    templateUrl: '/Templates/CustomerDetail.html',
    controller: 'customerDetailViewCtrl'
});
$routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
$locationProvider.html5mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
});

}]);
```

Additionally you have to add `<base href="/">` tag on the `index.html` page

Comment: Also i'm gettng $locationProvider.html5mode is not a function. Strange issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up with ngRoute and ui-router, use either one of those, In your case following should do the trick,

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
```

Comment: even if i remove i'm still getting the same error

TypeError: $locationProvider.html5mode is not a function

Comment: post what you have inside ctrl.js

Comment: i have posted the ctrl1.js